# How to debug Roslyn source generator in VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, roslyn, visual-studio-2022, sourcegenerators

**Context**

I was able to debug my source generator in VS 2019 by setting the project properties/debug Launch to Roslyn Component, then the target project combo to one of my consuming project:

[image]
[image]

Now this feature seems to be missing in VS 2022, I can not create a launch profile using the Launch Profile UI with similar settings.

**Question**

How can I debug Roslyn source generator in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: bit of a different approach, but I just use a regular test project, and set up the roslyn side in the test: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/tree/main/src/BuildToolsUnitTests

Comment: Many thx. Currently I am putting a Debugger.Launch() into my source generator Initialize(), then building the consuming project, which brings up the pick debugger dialog, where I pick the already running VS instance.

Comment: yeah, that's a lot of manual work compared to just hitting "debug" on a given test :)

Comment: @MarcGravell you should put that as an answer, it's by far the best solution.

Answer (score 20):

I got it working in VS 2022 17.1.0. Follow this instructions:

https://github.com/JoanComasFdz/dotnet-how-to-debug-source-generator-vs2022

Also make sure in the Visual Studio Installer that you have installed the .NET Compiler Platform SDK.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @JoanComasFdz. Your "Prerequisites" section says "The .NET Compiler Platform SDK must be installed.". I had assumed it was already installed. Pointing it out here made me doublecheck.

Comment: 17.7.0 is working for me, plus dont seem to have to restart VS when changing the code gen project.

Comment: My bad :-( I did not have the ".NET Compiler Platform SDK" installed. After installing it, works like a charm in VS 17.7.0 installation!